# How to enable the swf file autoplay on the mobile version of wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, mobile

I embedded the swf file on my wp page.(https://www.pacifictintlv.com/mobile).
But when viewing on mobile, it doesn`t work.
Can we just fix it so that it will automatically forward them to the Flash download link in case they don't have Flash enabled/installed or is there another fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Flash download link. Flash [hasn't been supported on Android for over five years](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2012/06/flash-player-and-android-update.html) and has famously [never been supported on iPhone](https://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/). [Flash itself will reach end of life in 2020.](https://theblog.adobe.com/adobe-flash-update/) There are ways for users to run Flash if they really want to, but it's too much to expect the average visitor to jump through those hoops.

Why are you using Flash at all? That page could easily be implemented with Javascript, and be far more accessible in the process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Would you assist me how can I convert the swf to js?
After check your answer, I tried to convert the swf file to html, but it doesn`t work correctly(some buttons click events don`t work and just worked as a video).So how can I implement with JS?